# ubuntu nohup doesn't work

Tags: python, git, ubuntu, nohup

I'm using AWS(ubuntu instance). I want to use nohup to run in the background.

I tried this code in my putty.

```
sudo nohup python3 manage.py runserver --settings=health.settings 0.0.0.0:80
```

then,

```
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

this code appears and website runs well.
But I press  'Ctrl + C', then nohup ends. 
What's wrong?

Comment: BTW, running an application server as root is generally a Bad Idea.

Comment: ...typically, you'll want to have something else in front of it (a load balancer, for example, or a high-performance web server for static content delivery, applying rewrite rules, enforcing security and running SSL, etc), so at that point you don't need to directly bind to port 80, so you don't need to even *temporarily* provide your app server with privileges (whereas every respectable frontend web server or load balancer has the ability to use those privileges to bind to port 80 and perhaps read SSL private keys and then drop them).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nohup` prevents HUP signals -- hangups, which are sent when the controlling terminal exits -- from being conveyed to the process. It doesn't ignore SIGINT, which are what ctrl+c sends.

Start your process **in the background** (with `&` as the following command separator):

```
sudo nohup python3 manage.py runserver --settings=health.settings 0.0.0.0:80 &
```

Or redirect stdin/stdout/stderr yourself and use the bash builtin `disown`, which does just as good a job of preventing HUPs from propagating as `nohup` does:

```
sudo python3 manage.py runserver ... </dev/null >runserver.log 2>&1 &
disown -h
```

...or, much better, use a *real* process supervision system ([Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), [DJB daemontools](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), [launchd](http://www.launchd.info/), [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), or one of the many others -- best practice is to use whichever one your operating system vendor ships out-of-the-box absent a compelling contrary reason) to run your process in the background and restart it when it dies.

Comment: ^C sends `SIGINT`

Comment: @AnthonySottile, thank you; corrected.

Comment: Thanks!, adding & works.  The website I'm making will be used by just 20 users. Is it okay to handle 20 users using just nohup, instead of web-server like nginx?

Comment: So, there are really three separate issues here, and I'm going to go into them one at a time. (1) when is it okay to run an application server as root rather than as a less privileged user?; (2) when is a it okay to use nohup instead of a process supervision system like systemd?; (3) when is it okay to directly expose an application server to the Internet, without being behind a web server?

Comment: (1) - granted, I'm working in the security industry, but I'd really argue "never". Doing this makes any kind of compromise of the service into a compromise of the whole server, rather than something contained to the individual service (and *hopefully*, if you're being careful about that account's privileges, only able to access its data and not change its code). Doubly so when attached to the Internet -- there may be only 20 people you *want* to have using your server, but if it's accessible to millions more, you need to plan on being scanned for / attacked using common vulnerabilities.

Comment: ...mitigating factors there are if your application is only accessible by someone connecting via a VPN rather than the 'net at large. Granted, one *should* try to be secure at multiple layers -- defense-in-depth is a thing -- but having an outer layer will at least keep the random scanners trying to attack anything they can find out.

Comment: (2) - "When is it okay to use nohup instead of a process supervision system like systemd?" -- basically, whenever you don't care if your service comes back up automatically after a failure. Amazon *does* reboot boxes randomly -- if it's acceptable to have your service be down until you've logged in and run a command after that happened, there you are, but if this is something you're running a company off (or showing to people you'd later like to work with in a professional capacity), it's worth doing it right.

Comment: (3) - "When is it okay to directly expose an application server without a web server in front?" -- so, here, a lot of the factors get into what capabilities you need. Assuming you fixed getting the application server exposed on port 80 *without* using `sudo` to give it root privileges a different way (like putting it on port 8080 and telling iptables to map inbound requests on 80 to local port 8080), then this isn't really compelling unless you're hitting performance issues or you need capabilities that a proper web server would give you for free.

Comment: (re: "performance issues" -- particularly relevant if you're serving large amounts of content that *doesn't* need to be dynamically generated; nginx/apache/etc can generally do that extremely well)

Comment: ...to have an error page of your choice instead of a browser-level error when the service is down, for instance, is definitely a case you'll want a frontend web server for. But that's much less of a priority than (1) implementing principal-of-least-privilege to contain the value of successful attacks; and (2) ensuring that services your site depends on are properly supervised and will be restarted automatically if they fail.

Comment: (BTW, I don't know which OS image you're using, but systemd is pretty near ubiquitous on newer Linux distros these days; if you have a `/usr/lib/systemd/system` directory, you can look at all the `*.service` files in it to get an idea of what they look like).